# Bounds for analytic functions using Cauchy's integral formula

Tags: complex-analysis

Problem: Suppose $f$ is analytic inside and on the unit circle $|z|=1$. Prove that if $|f(z)| \leq M$ for $|z|=1$, then $|f(0)| \leq M$ and $|f'(0)| \leq M$. What estimate can you give for $|f^n(0)|$?

Attempt:
In Cauchy's integral formula  $f^{n}(z_0)=\frac{n!}{2 \pi i} \int_{|z|=1} \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}dz$

To get $f$ as a function of $z$ replace $z$ with $\zeta$ and $z_0$ with $z$

So $f^{n}(z)=\frac{n!}{2 \pi i} \int_{|\zeta|=1} \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z)^{n+1}}d\zeta$

Then $f^{n}(0)=\frac{n!}{2 \pi i} \int_{|\zeta|=1} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta^{n+1}}d\zeta$

Then by the ML inequality

$|f^{n}(0)|=|\frac{n!}{2 \pi i} \int_{|\zeta|=1} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta^{n+1}}d\zeta| \leq \frac{n!}{2 \pi }\frac{M 2\pi}{\zeta^{n+1}}$

The answer given in the back of the book says

$|f^{n}(0)| \leq \frac{n!}{2 \pi }M 2\pi=n!M$ thus $|f(0)| \leq M$ and $|f'(0)| \leq M$

Here I am confused why 1 is an upper bound for $\frac{1}{|\zeta^{n+1}|}$ I thought $\zeta$ would be a point on the circle $|\zeta|=1$ and since $|\zeta|$ would be a real number between $0$ and $1$, this would make the numerator larger so that $\frac{n!}{2 \pi }\frac{M 2\pi}{\zeta^{n+1}} \geq \frac{n!}{2 \pi }M 2\pi=n!M$

What's going on here? Also is it right to change the variables in Cauchy's formula from $z$ to $\zeta$ and from $z_0$ to $z$, and since the integral was along the contour $|z|=1$ would this change of variables imply the new contour would be $|\zeta|=1$?

Comment: Remark on notation: when you replace $z$ with $\zeta$, do so in the integral as well, so the integral has $d \zeta$ in it rather than $d z$.

Comment: Oh my bad sorry about that

Comment: @ChaitanyaTappu Also is it correct to interpret that $\zeta$ is a point on the contour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the magnitude in the inequality.
The correct inequality is 
$$\left|f^{n}(0)\right|=\left|\frac{n!}{2 \pi i} \int_{|\zeta|=1} \frac{f(\zeta)}{\zeta^{n+1}}d\zeta\right| \leq \left|\frac{n!}{2 \pi i}\right| \int_{|\zeta|=1} \frac{\left|f(\zeta)\right|}{\left|\zeta^{n+1}\right|}|d\zeta| \le \frac{n!}{2 \pi }\frac{M 2\pi}{1^{n+1}} = n!M$$

Note that the integrand is $\frac {f (\zeta)}{\zeta^{n + 1}}$, so while using the ML inequality you have to bound the magnitude of this expression as $\zeta$ ranges over the contour $|\zeta| = 1$.
That turns out to be $\left|\frac{f (\zeta)}{\zeta^{n + 1}} \right| \le \frac M {1^{n + 1}}$.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand. Is it correct if I change the variables that the contour goes from $|z|=1$ to $|\zeta|=1$. There is a solutions manual that I'm looking at which leaves the contour as $|z|=1$ even though the integral is with respect to $\zeta$?

Comment: Yes, the contour is $|\zeta| = 1$. The dummy variable of integration should be the same as the independent variable in the integrand, which should be same as the variable used in defining the contour.

Comment: Sounds good thanks